# What does "Class<?" mean in Java?

Tags: java

I ran across this function definition :

```
public Collection<Class<? extends SomeClass>> someFunc();
```

What does the `Class<?` part mean? Coming from C++, it looks like templates, but I'm not quite sure if this is the case, since there are constructs in Java that look like C++, but aren't quite the same. In either case, I'd like to know what this means and how it's used.

I looked up what this meant, but I couldn't find anything relevant (perhaps there's a special name for this operator that I'm not aware of) - looking up "`Class<?` in Java" returned results similar to "what is a class in java". I'm fairly new to Java programming, so my apologies if this is something basic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=class+with+question+mark+java  
May the power of google be with you

Comment: Are you asking about `Class` objects or about generics?

Comment: Also, why do you think it's `Class<?`? What about the `>` at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have come across is Java generics. Generics are Java's parallel to C++ templates. The question mark symbol `?` stands for a wildcard.

To learn more, you can look for these terms or directly go to Oracle tutorial:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/